# Is this matrix equal to the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove if this matrix is unitary:
$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -i \\i & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ 
So after multiplying it by it's conjugate transpose I got the answer $\begin{bmatrix}-i & 0 \\0 &-i \end{bmatrix}$
**Is this equal to the identity matrix?**

Comment: What do you think the identity matrix is?

Comment: That’s $\displaystyle\sigma_{y}$: A [Pauli Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to prove that the Pauli Matrix is unitary. From what I know, a unitary matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{pmatrix}$, then $\bar A^T=A$.

Now you can check that $A\bar A^T=A^2=I$.

Comment: So just to clarify, the second matrix I put in the question is equal to the identity matrix right?

Comment: No it isn't.  Because $-i\ne1$.

Comment: Right, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix is unitary if its conjugate transpose is also its inverse.

Call your first matrix $A$. The conjugate transpose of your first matrix is
$ \bar{A^t} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &i \\ -i &0 \end{bmatrix}^T = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i &0 \end{bmatrix}$
So you can see that your matrix is equal to its conjugate transpose. That property is called Hermitian. Have you tried multiplying
$ A \bar{A^t} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i &0 \end{bmatrix}^2 = \ \ ?$

Comment: I did try that, I actually got the answer I put in my question. Is that right? Also, I heard that another way that you can tell if a matrix is unitary by seeing if the cross product of matrix A and conjugate tranpose A = Identity matrix. Can you verify this?